# All the combination of two list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a Python question.  I have two list of lists as follows:

```
    list_1 = [["A1","A2"],["B1","B2"],["C1","C2"]]
    list_2 = [["A3","A4"],["B3","B4"],["C3"]]
```

I am looking for all the possible combination of these two list with only one element from each list within list. Also if the combination has only one "C" it should come from list_1 (the list which has two "C"s). For instance:

```
    output:
    [["A1","A3"],["B1","B3"],["C1","C3"]]
    [["A2","A3"],["B1","B3"],["C2","C3"]]
    [["A1","A4"],["B2","B3"],["C2"]]
```

Can this be done with the basic Python library?

**Edit**

This is my best try so far:

```
    combi = []
    for i in range(len(list_1)):
        for j in range(len(list_1[i])):
            for k in range(len(list_2[i])):
                combi.extend([list_1[i][j],list_2[i][k]])
```

However, this did not get me what I hoped for.

Comment: I guess that ``itertools`` can help (see for combinations, permutations). I am afraid I did not get the logic behind "C". Why is "C2" a single value in the last list?

Comment: Looks like an interview or homework question, post a snippet of what you tried before

Comment: Thank you @MaximIvanov. It is possible to have one or two "C" in the combination list. So if it is a two "C" list, one of them will be "C3" and one can be either "C1" or "C2"; if it is a one "C" list, it has to be either "C1" or "C2".

Comment: @GaëtanGR, I tried a multiple for loop approach which not only is not efficient, also didn't give me the results I hoped for!

Comment: **show your code**

Comment: It is a gene-related question. list_1 is mom's genes, and list_2 is dad's genes. looking for all the possible children.

Comment: @GaëtanGR Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not sure you missed these few pairs in the `Output`: ['A2', 'A4']  and ['B2', 'B4']?   It's confusing...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I really understand your req. some of the output is inconsistent or missing as my post indicated.  So I've tried to `guess` what you want to make the combinations from each list (one at a time) as your title description stated.

You can modify the sample to suite your needs, if there is a gap in understanding. (this should be very close ... though)

```
from itertools import product

list_1 = [["A1","A2"],["B1","B2"]] #,["C1","C2"]]   # for simple test, reduce C-lst
list_2 = [["A3","A4"],["B3","B4"]] #,["C3"]]
combs =  []   # set()

for one in list_1:
    for two in list_2:
      
        for p in product(one, two):
            #print(p)      # can comment out
            combs.append(list(p))
               

print(combs)
```